# Get the length of a string containing Null terminated string

Tags: c++, string, null-terminated

I'm using the XOR encryption so when I'm going to decrypt my string I need to get the length of that string.

I tried in this way:

```html
string to_decode = "abcd\0lom";
int size = to_decode.size();
```

or in this way:

```
string to_decode = "abcd\0lom";
int size = to_decode.lenght();
```

Both are wrong because the string contain `\0`.
So how can I have the right length of my string?

Comment: _"Both are wrong because the string contain \0"_ Nope, your assumption is wrong. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size)

Comment: You loose the end during initialization of the std::string with a null terminated c-string. Otherwise size and length are synonym and will deliver the correct length (even if the std::string contains a zero).

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize the `std::string`, with a `\0` in the middle, you loose all data ahead of it. If you think about it, a `std::string` is just a wrapper for a `char*`, and that gets terminated by a null termination `\0`. If the `\0`, doesn't have any meaning in the `string`, then you could escape it, like this:

```
string to_decode = "abcd\\0lom";
```

and the size would be 9. Otherwise, you could a container (eg: `std::vector`), of `char`'s for the data storage

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the initialisation, not with the size. If you use the constructor taking a `const char *`, it interprets that argument as a NUL-terminated string. So your `std::string` is only initialised with the string `abcd`.

You need to use a range-based constructor:

```
const char data[] = "abcd\0lom";
std::string to_decode(data, data + (sizeof data) - 1);  // -1 to not include terminating NUL
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f357cbcb8ddbadc)

However, be careful with such strings. While `std::string` can deal with embedded NULs perfectly fine, the result of `c_str()` will behave as "truncated" as far as all NUL-terminated APIs are concerned.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the problem is that the code uses the constructor that takes `const char*`, and that only copies up to the `\0`. But, by a very strange coincidence, `std::string` has a constructor that can handle that case:

```
const char text[] = "abcd\0lom";
std::string to_decode(text, sizeof(text) - 1);
int size = to_decode.size();
```

The constructor will copy as many characters as you tell it to.